# Query to calculate both cumulative and total SUM over salary

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Name  Location  Salary
smith newyork   6000 
adam  dallas    5000
rams  delhi     7000
scott laondon   4000
```

and output should be like this

```
Name  Location  Salary Running_salary  total_salary
smith newyork   6000    6000            22000
adam  dallas    5000    11000           22000 
rams  delhi     7000    18000           22000
scott lndon     4000    22000           22000
```

Comment: Question is not clear?

Comment: How is `Running_salary` column related to 1st table?

Comment: total_salary is sum(salary) and running salary is sal of first employee + salary of second employee and so on

Comment: How would you define the order? For example, if rams comes before adam, running salary for second column will change, is there some logic behind that?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name,
location,
salary,
SUM(salary) OVER ( ORDER BY name) AS running_Salary,
/* order by name can replaced with rownum or rowid , but has to be some
column for perfect ordering as internal order is not judgeable */
SUM(salary) OVER () AS total_salary
FROM yourtable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f5f8/3)

Comment: You can use `sum(salary) over() as total_sum` instead of subquery

Comment: @VigneshKumar thanks, difficult to type much in ipad. so skipped few.

Comment: @user3239175 in which order you want this?

Comment: when i am executing the query smith is going to last row but i need him in the first row only and the order should not be changed in the name column

Comment: @user3239175 the order is not in our hands.. until we give it programmatically some logic in our query.  may can give rowid a try. But may not be perfect! Try replacing order by name in my query with order by rowid.

Comment: by changing it rownum its working fine once again thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT  'smith' AS Name, 'newyork' AS Location, 6000 AS Salary FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT  'adam', 'dallas', 5000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT  'rams', 'delhi', 7000 FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT  'scott', 'laondon', 4000  FROM dual
),
derived_cte AS (
SELECT rownum rn, name, location, salary
  FROM cte)
SELECT dc.name, dc.location, dc.salary,
       dc.salary + (select sum(dc_in.salary)
                      from derived_cte dc_in
                     where dc_in.rn < dc.rn) AS running_salary,
       (select sum(salary) from cte) AS total_salary
  FROM derived_cte dc;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name    location  salary  running_salary  total_salary
------- --------- ------- --------------  --------------
smith   newyork   6000    22000
adam    dallas    5000    11000           22000
rams    delhi     7000    18000           22000
scott   laondon   4000    22000           22000
```